# ASP.NET MVC 2: Deserialize SPROC Response

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I need to ask a general question. I don't have the code in front of me because I'm writing this on my iPhone.

I have a Class that represents a certain XML schema. I have a SPROC that returns this XML. What I need to do is deserialize the XML to this Class.

XML:

```
<xml>
     <person>
             <firstName>Bob</firstName>
             <lastName>Robby</lastName>
     </person>
</xml>
```

I need to deserialize this XML into the custom Person Class so I can loop through this Model and spit it out in the View. I'm sure there's some kind of casting involved, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: .NET 4? You could really use the Dynamic keyword here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution:

```
 public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {


            string xml = @"<xml><person><firstName>Bob</firstName><lastName>Robby</lastName></person></xml>";

            var doc = XElement.Parse(xml);
            var person = (from x in doc.Elements("person") select x).FirstOrDefault();

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));

            var sr = new StringReader(person.ToString());
            // Use the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
            var myPerson = (Person)serializer.Deserialize(sr);

        }

    }
```

And Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication3 {

    [XmlRoot("person")]
    public class Person {

        [XmlElement("firstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("lastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in linq it would be something like this

```
XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Parse(yourXml)    
var people = (from x in xmlFile.Descendants("person")
              select new Person(){
                      firstname = (string)x.Element("firstname").Value,
                      lastname = (string)x.Element("lastname").Value
              });
```